# Two-Dimensional Sorting Lower Bound

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, matrix

Given: an arbitrary array of n^2 unsorted numbers
Output: n x n matrix of the inputs, where all rows and columns are sorted.

For example, if n = 3, n^2 = 9, and the array is {1,2,...,9}
Possible outputs include:

1 4 7

2 5 8

3 6 9

and

1 3 5

2 4 6

7 8 9

So I know that this problem can be done in O(n^2log n) time simply by sorting the n^2 numbers and then using the first n numbers as the first row, the second n numbers as the second row, and so on, but how would I prove a matching lower bound, i.e. Ω(n^2log n)?

Comment: Yeah it was me who posted the other one, but the format got messed up. Would it be nlogn for each row and there are n rows, so n^2log(2n) which is Ω(n^2log n)?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat It is not straightforward that your hint actually helps.  There are `O(n)` diagonals of size `O(n)` each that have no necessary order relation.  That's `O(n^2 log(n))` work to finish sorting.

Comment: @btilly I retract my retraction. Look at the constants.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I agree, your hint does lead to a proof.  There is a way to start with the partially sorted data structure and finish with the sorted arrays using `Ω(n^2 log(n))` fewer comparisons than the best average for sorting an array from scratch.  Therefore you can't get to that intermediate state without that many comparisons.  But the argument will require careful analysis, not the usual handwaving we get away with.